# Show that the integers $0$, $1$ and $3$ are eigenvalues of $T : L^2[-\pi, \pi] \to L^2[-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

Define the function $x \in L^2[-\pi, \pi]$ by
\begin{equation*}
  x(t) = \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      0 , && -\pi \leq t < 0, \\
      1 , && 0\leq t \leq \pi
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
and the  operator $T : L^2[-\pi, \pi] \to L^2[-\pi, \pi]$ by setting

\begin{equation}
  Tf = \langle f, e_0\rangle e_0 + 3\langle f, e_{-1}\rangle e_{-1} + 3\langle f, e_1\rangle e_1\,,
\end{equation}

where $e_n(t) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm e^{\mathrm i n t}$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Show that the integers $0$, $1$ and $3$ are the only eigenvalues of $T$.

### An answer that came up short

In the (a) part of this question, I came up with the basis representation of $x \in L^2$:

\begin{equation}
  x = \sqrt{ \frac{ \pi }{ 2 } }
    + \frac 1 { \sqrt{2 \pi} }\sum_{n \neq 0} \left( \frac{ \mathrm e^{\mathrm i n \pi } - 1 }{ \mathrm i n } \right) e_n \,.
\end{equation}

I then proceeded to find out what $Tf$ looks like:
\begin{align*}
  Tf
  &= \langle f, e_0\rangle  e_0 + 3 \langle f, e_{-1}\rangle e_{-1}
    + 3\langle f, e_1\rangle  e_1 \\
  &= \sqrt{\frac{ \pi }{ 2 } } \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ 2\pi } }
      + \frac 3 { \sqrt{2 \pi} } \left( \frac{ \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \pi } - 1 }{ - \mathrm i } \right) \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm e^{- \mathrm i t}
      + \frac 3 { \sqrt{2 \pi} } \left( \frac{ \mathrm e^{ \mathrm i \pi} - 1 }{ \mathrm i } \right) \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm e^{ \mathrm i t} \\
    &= \frac 1 2
        + \frac 3 { 2 \pi } \left( \frac{ -2 }{ - \mathrm i } \right) \mathrm e^{- \mathrm i t}
        + \frac 3 { 2 \pi } \left( \frac{ -2 }{ \mathrm i } \right) \mathrm e^{ \mathrm i t}
      = \frac 1 2
        + \frac {6} { 2\pi\mathrm i }  \mathrm e^{- \mathrm i t}
        - \frac {6 } {2\pi\mathrm i }  \mathrm e^{\mathrm i t}\\
    &= \frac 1 2
        + \frac {6} { \pi } \frac{ \mathrm e^{- \mathrm i t} - \mathrm e^{ \mathrm i t} }{ 2\mathrm i }
      = \frac 1 2 - \frac {6} { \pi } \frac{ \mathrm e^{ \mathrm i t} - \mathrm e^{- \mathrm i t} }{ 2\mathrm i }
      = \frac 1 2 - \frac {6} { \pi } \sin{t} \\
    &= \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
      0 , && -\pi \leq t < 0\,, \\
      1 , && 0\leq t \leq \pi \,.
      \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{align*}

In other words,
\begin{equation}
\sin{t} = \frac \pi {12}
\end{equation}
when $t \in [-\pi,0)$ and when $t \in [0, \pi]$
\begin{equation}
\sin{t} = -\frac{ \pi }{ 12 },
\end{equation}
which is not possible as $\sin t$ is not constant on either of these two intervals.

Why is this approach not working?

Comment: The way you wrote it, your operator is only defined for a single function $x\in L^2$. It is not even clear how it acts on other elements.

Comment: It seems to me that parts a) and b) of the problem are not connected. In part a), it's necessary to expand the function $x$ in a Fourier series, and in part b), find the eigenvalues of the operator defined on all $L^2$. Am i right? By the way, should one of the coefficients in the definition of the operator $T$ be equal to 2?

Comment: @thing No, I made a typo. Just a sec...

Comment: Just consider the equation $Tf=\lambda f$. If $\lambda=0$ then, for example $f=e_2$ is a eigenfunction. If $\lambda\ne0$, rewrite $Tx=\lambda\sum(f,e_k)e_k$ and and try to multiply this equality scalarly by something (for example, by $e_0$).